# Clustering with restrictions - Silhouette and C index metrics

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I am working on clustering with DBSCAN but with a certain constraint: the points inside a cluster have to be not only near in a Euclidean distance way but also near in a geographic distance way. It is feasible if you use the pseudocode and work on it.

My issue however is about the proper metric on evaluating the clustering results. Applying the silhouette and c index metrics I get (as expected) results lower than the ones of clustering without constraints. A visual check shows that my clustering is well implemented but it seems as though that the interval of values of the metrics (for example [-1,1] for silhouette and [0,1] for C index) has changed. How can I verify that? I don't want a biased metric.

Comment: How does this differ from GDBSCAN? Why do you think the intervals have changed?

Comment: I am afraid that since i modified the algorithm with the mentioned restriction, there is no way to reach the optimal value of the metric which is the one that matches the no-restriction clustering. Could you cliarify your comment about GDBSCAN?

Comment: It sounds as if you reinvented a simple instantiation of the GDBSCAN pattern. Also I don't think Silhouette or C-index work well with noise and non-spherical clusters.